# How solve Sqlite Cursor exception in android

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

I have get Exception after succesfylly fetching data.I have **cursor close**.

**Exception-**

```
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44c115b8 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44c10768 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44c0f918 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44c0df08 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44c0c990 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
11-06 14:31:09.942: I/dalvikvm(598):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

**Sql Statements**

```
           String tableName="StateList_Tbl";
         String databaseName="TravelguideDb";
         int databaseVersion=3;

         assetDatabaseHelper=new AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(HomeScreen.this, databaseName,databaseVersion);
         assetDatabaseHelper.openDatabase();
         assetDatabaseHelper.openReadableMode();
         groupEntityList=new ArrayList<GroupEntity>();



        String selectQuery = "SELECT State_id,State_name FROM " +tableName +" where country_part=36";


       groupCursor=assetDatabaseHelper.executeQuery(selectQuery);

        if (groupCursor.moveToFirst()) 
        {
                 do {
                     groupEntityObj=new GroupEntity();
                     groupEntityObj.setGroupId(groupCursor.getInt(0));
                     System.out.println("stateid"+groupCursor.getInt(0));
                     groupEntityObj.setGroupName(groupCursor.getString(1));
                     System.out.println("stateid"+groupCursor.getString(1));
                    String stateQuery="SELECT State_id,State_name FROM " +tableName +" where country_part="+groupCursor.getInt(0);
                    stateCursor=assetDatabaseHelper.executeQuery(stateQuery);
                    stateArrayList=new ArrayList<StateMetaData>();
                    if(stateCursor.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        do{
                         stateMetaDataObj=new StateMetaData();
                         stateMetaDataObj.setStateId(stateCursor.getInt(0));
                         System.out.println("stateid"+stateCursor.getInt(0));
                         stateMetaDataObj.setStateName(stateCursor.getString(1));
                         System.out.println("stateid"+stateCursor.getString(1));
                         stateArrayList.add(stateMetaDataObj);

                        }while(stateCursor.moveToNext());
                    }


                    groupEntityObj.setStatesList(stateArrayList);

                    groupEntityList.add(groupEntityObj);
                 } while (groupCursor.moveToNext());

        }

        System.out.println("gr "+groupEntityList.size());
        stateCursor.close();
        groupCursor.close();
        assetDatabaseHelper.close();

        System.out.println("cursor"+stateCursor.getColumnCount());
        System.out.println("cursor"+groupCursor);
```

**AssetDatabaseOpenHelper class**

```
 public class AssetDatabaseOpenHelper {
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabaseObj;
    private String database_name;
    private CreateQueries createQueriesObj;
    private MySQLiteHelper mySQLitehelperObj;
    private int database_version;

    private  String databaseName="TravelguideDb";
    private  int databaseVersion=3;
    public AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(Context context,String databaseName,int database_version) {
        this.context = context;
        this.database_name=databaseName;
        this.database_version=database_version;
    }



    public AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
        this.database_name = databaseName;
        this.database_version = databaseVersion;
    }



    public void openDatabase() {
        mySQLitehelperObj = new MySQLiteHelper(context, database_name,
                database_version);

        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(database_name);
System.out.println("Assests"+dbFile.exists());
        if (!dbFile.exists()) {
            try {
                copyDatabase(dbFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
            //  e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
 //  sqliteDatabaseObj= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
//        sqliteDatabaseObj = mySQLitehelperObj.getReadableDatabase();

    }
public void openReadableMode()
{
     sqliteDatabaseObj = mySQLitehelperObj.getReadableDatabase();
}
public void openWriteableMode()
{
     sqliteDatabaseObj = mySQLitehelperObj.getWritableDatabase();
}
public void close() {

    mySQLitehelperObj.close();
}

    private void copyDatabase(File dbFile) throws IOException {

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);

        InputStream is = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
        {
       is = context.getAssets().open("TravelguideDb.sqlite.00"+1);
         int length;
        while ((length=is.read(buffer))!=-1) {
            os.write(buffer,0,length);
        }
        is.close();
    }

        os.flush();
        os.close();
        is.close();
    }

   public Cursor executeQuery(String query)
   {
     Cursor outputCursor=  sqliteDatabaseObj.rawQuery(query, null);
    return outputCursor;
   }
    public void createTable(String tableName, String[] columns, String[] value) {
        createQueriesObj = new CreateQueries();
        String createTableQuery = createQueriesObj.CreateTableQuery(tableName,
                columns, value);
        sqliteDatabaseObj.execSQL(createTableQuery);
        System.out.println("Query" + createTableQuery);
    }
    public void deleteTable(String tableName) 
    {
        sqliteDatabaseObj.execSQL("Drop table " + tableName);
    }

    public void deleteAllDataFromTable(String tableName) {
        // truncate table
        sqliteDatabaseObj.delete(tableName, null, null);
    }
    public void deletePerticularRows(String tableName, String whereClause,
            String[] whereArgs) {
        sqliteDatabaseObj.delete(tableName, whereClause, whereArgs);
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllRows(String tableName) {

        return sqliteDatabaseObj.query(tableName, null, null, null, null, null,
                null);
    }
    public Cursor selectOnWhereCondition(String tableName,
            String[] columnsToSelect, String whereColumnName,
            String[] whereEqualsTo, String groupBy, String having,
            String orderBy) {
        return sqliteDatabaseObj.query(tableName, columnsToSelect,
                whereColumnName, whereEqualsTo, groupBy, having, orderBy);
    }




}
```

Comment: if you are using cursor in UI thread then user context.startManagingCursor(cursor) function and in other thread use cursor.close or cursor.deactivate when you no longer require cursor

Comment: Note that you're opening stateCursor multiple times (once for each iteration in groupCursor) but only closing it at the end. This is probably the cause of the problem and it also exposes your code to a NullPointerException in the instance that groupCursor.moveToFirst() returns false.

Comment: @PhillipFitzsimmons thanks now i am not getting exception.but why got value after closing cursor  System.out.println("cursor"+stateCursor.getColumnCount());

Comment: In fact there's no reason why a cursor shouldn't return a value from getColumnCount after it's been closed and indeed there's nothing preventing an implementation of Cursor (which is, after all, just an interface) from dealing with close() any way it sees fit. In the case of SqlLiteCursor getColumnCount() returns the length of an array that was instantiated with the query and remains valid after close().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing cursors for log messages after they have been closed.

To ensure proper closing, use cursors like this:

```
    Cursor c = DB.rawQuery(queryString);
    try{    
        while(c.moveToNext()){

           Cursor c2 = DB.rawQuery(queryString2);
           try{
               while(c2.moveToNext()){                 
               //--do stuff---
               }

           } finally {
               c2.close();
           }

        }
    }finally {
        c.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.Problem is solve by mr. Phillip Fitzsimmons suggestion.

Comment: I like the pattern and applied it through out my db adapter.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Once you open the `Cursor` or the `SQLiteDatabase` object, you must close when your read/write database task and cursor task are over. In other words, When a cursor object or SQLiteDatabase object are no more need to be accessed, you have to close it for each time you open them.

Comment: Thanks for answer.Problem is solve by mr. Phillip Fitzsimmons suggestion.